# How do I solo mine on a mac?

Tags: solo-mining, cpu-mining, miner-configuration

I know it's pointless. I just want to learn how to do it. Are there any guides out there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. For Mac OSX users, you must have Snow Leopard (10.6) or newer
   installed.
2. A fully-connected BitCoin wallet. see http://bitcoin.org/
3. If this is the first time you have launched BitCoin, it must
   download and verify all the existing blocks in the system.

> ```
>  This can
>     take an hour or longer - just ignore it for a while.
> ```
>
> Update: since the time of this post the block chain has grown It can take several days on a slow connection to download and is currently pushing past 15GB

1. Install DiabloMiner see
   https://github.com/Diablo-D3/DiabloMiner/wiki/Solo-Mining